# Get all information after URL question mark in Nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I am attempting to make a page that allows me to visit `www.example.com/create?453lk6m4y` and create the account linked to that ID through the page `createUser.php?id=453lk6m4y`. The issue that I'm running into is that if I pass that straight to the PHP script, the GET request sets the key as `453lk6m4y` and the value as nothing.

In other words, if I visit that url, the page understands the GET request

```
Array
(
    [453lk6m4y] => 
)
```

I wanted to rewrite the URL via Nginx rewrites. I have this so far:

`rewrite ^/create(\?.*)?$ /createUser.php?id=$1 last; #user creation page`

However, this rewrite changes the get request to reflect the following:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 
    [453lk6m4y] => 
)
```

Any ways to rewrite the url so that the GET request would reflect

```
Array
(
    [id] => 453lk6m4y
)
```

Comment: I'd recommend not using the `?` but a `/`. So `www.example.com/create/453lk6m4y`

Comment: That does work, but is it possible to make it work with a `?`?

Comment: `?` is the prefix for the query string. Not the URL. While it likely is possible, it's not *right*.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? If you post an answer with your first comment and an elaboration on why it's not right, I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: Can't you just send *all* traffic to a controlling PHP page, and then parse it in there? You'll have more control over the data.

Comment: I am sending all the data to PHP. It's just that the data is in a form that I won't know for sure what it will be valued. If the Id I needed was the value of a key, I would be able to process it easier. But since it's the key of an array, I don't know what that key is.

Answer (score 0):

First I'm actually not sure if `www.example.com/create?453lk6m4y` is a valid url:

- `?` is defined as the separater between the location and the (get)parameters
- get parameters are normally of the normally of the form `<parameter>=<value>`, with a `&` separator between different parameters

That said if you look at http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#Variables you'll see all the standard variables available in nginx:

- Specifically the `$args`-variable will hold the whole of the get parameters, i.e. everything after the `?`
- you also have `$arg_PARAMETER`-variables, to access the individual parameter values. (So if you have a url `example.org/createuser.php?id=1234&page=abc` then you have a variable `$arg_id` with value `1234` and a variable `$arg_page` with value `abc`)